# How to bind bool? to RadioButton in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I don't know how to bind nullable boolean field to RadioButton in ASP.net.

Following code works well for non-nullable field

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbStatus" runat="server" Text="Accepted" Checked='<%# Bind("Status") %>' />
```

Can you tell me how I can bind nullable boolean field to RadioButton?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the `Bind` method do exactly?

Comment: It binds boolean value to RadioButton, so whenever user changes the status of RadioButton, new value assignes to associated field("Status" ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible, unfortunately you can use the `Bind()` syntax only on non-nullable values. Bind is [fairly limited](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx) in what it accepts for arguments. Unlike [`DataBinder.Eval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval.aspx) which is simply a method call.