# Bind SelectedValue in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, data-binding

I don't know why, but I'm really struggling with this. I want to bind a nullable boolean property to a RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="MyControl" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("InstanceOfMyModel.MyProperty") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I can access the value through `MyControl`, but I can't seem to bind the `SelectedValue` property. The code behind for this page has a public property `InstanceOfMyModel` (backed by Session) of `MyMode`l which has the nullable boolean property `MyProperty`. Changing the type to string doesn't do anything. The 'bound' property doesn't change: if it was a string before, it's the same string; if it was null, it's still null.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there some suppressed conversion issue? I'm not getting compile or runtime errors.

Comment: I found this on a brief search... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482477/how-to-bind-bool-to-radiobutton-in-asp-net hope it helps...

Comment: @Angela Thanks for trying. That case is trying to bind to a single radio button's `Checked` property which is a boolean, but the `SelectedValue` property for a RadioButtonList is a string.

Comment: If `MyControl` is not in a Control that repeats data (ListView, GridView etc), Your binding will not work. Use code behind: `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { MyControl.SelectedValue = "False"; }`

Comment: @VDWWD I'm not repeating data, so it sounds like you understand what's going on. I was hoping to avoid assignments in the codebehind, but it looks like I'm out of luck. If you want to post an answer explaining why it doesn't work (and what it would take to get it working?), I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Posted a solution without code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedValue` property cannot be set declaratively. You need to do this in code behind.

```
MyControl.SelectedValue = "False";
```

Or if you really do not want to use code behind you can use JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myControl = "<%= MyControl.ClientID %>";
    var myValue = "<%= InstanceOfMyModel.MyProperty %>";
    if (myValue == "True") {
        document.getElementById(myControl + "_0").checked = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(myControl + "_1").checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't include why it works in a control repeating data in contrast to this, but I guess I'll accept it.